# What does this Oompa Loompa whisper to Wonka in the T.V. Room?

Tags: dialogue, willy-wonka-and-chocolate-factory

In *Willy Wonka and the Chocolate Factory*, what does the Oompa Loompa whisper to Wonka before he takes Mike T.V. (inside his Mother's Purse) to the Taffy Pulling Room?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

> In Willy Wonka and the Chocolate Factory, what does the Oompa Loompa whisper to Wonka before he takes Mike T.V. (inside his Mother's Purse) to the Taffy Pulling Room?

#### The Oompa Loompa was whispering -- should something go wrong when restoring Mike, will I get in trouble?

Just after Mike is shrunk and placed in his mom's purse, Wonka explains that Mike can [theoretically] be restored by using the Taffy stretching machine.

When issuing directions to the Oompa Loompa in question, Wonka responds to a comment/question by saying that he won't hold the Oompa Loompa responsible..  *should something go wrong*.

> WONKA: (continuous) Well, fortunately small boys are extremely springy 
>   and elastic, so I think we'll put him in my special taffy-pulling machine.  That should do the trick.
>
> MRS. TEEVEE: Taffy . . .
>
> WONKA: (to an Oompa Loompa) **To the taffy-pulling room. You'll find the boy in his mother's purse.  *But be extremely careful.***
>
> MRS. TEEVEE: (losing it) T-t-taffy pull--  (as the Oompa Loompa whispers to Willy Wonka) Oh, what's he saying?
>
> WONKA: (to the Oompa Loompa) **No, no, I won't hold you responsible.**

The Oompa Loompa whispered this to avoid upsetting Mike's mom, but it would seem Wonka's non-discreet response had that effect anyway, as Mike's mom then faints.